# Can I get attribute information about SVG nodes/parent nodes when using SVGLoader?

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to set something up where I import an SVG using the SVGLoader, but am hoping to render each shape differently depending on attributes on the node, or based on the ID of a parent `<g>` element, but I can't seem to figure out how I might determine those things.

The [documentation for SVGLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/SVGLoader) states:

> The function receives the loaded SVGDocument as an argument.

But it appears that the link on 'SVGDocument' no longer works, and in practice I seem to get an array of 'paths', and I can't find any reference to the SVG element nodes that these paths correspond to.

Is there a way to get such information, either through the SVGLoader, or another process?

Comment: It should say "The function receives an array of `ShapePath` as an argument." You can hack `SVGLoader`, adding `path.style = style;`, or whatever attributes you want.

Comment: @WestLangley that's not a bad idea; it's a pretty easy change. I just tried doing `path.node = node;` which pretty much gives me the ability to look up all attributes, all parent nodes, and everything I might need. I do hate to have to modify a library file though. I wonder if having something like a node reference associated to the path would be useful enough to warrant doing a pull request to add it in for real? Perhaps returning a Map of nodes to paths instead of an array...

Comment: It's an examples file; I think it is reasonable to modify it. Feel free to propose your Map idea if you want.